# File already exists error (800A003A) when trying to rename file unless it is already named as desired

Tags: vbscript

Having issues getting the following VBScript to work. Near the end of the script, I am attempting to rename the file to STAMPS IMPORT.csv, unless the file is already named STAMPS IMPORT.csv. I feel like the if statement I wrote *should* work, but it isn't, because when I run the script on a file named STAMPS IMPORT.csv it gives me a File already exists error. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
' Define the path to the CSV file
Dim filePath
filePath = WScript.Arguments(0)

' Add header
Dim header
header = "shipmethod,name,phone,company,address1,address2,address3,city,state,zip,ordernum,orderdate,shipdate,trackingno" ' Replace with your desired header line

' Create a FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Check if the file exists
If objFSO.FileExists(filePath) Then
    ' Read the existing content of the file
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1) ' 1 = ForReading

    ' Read the current content of the file
    existingContent = objFile.ReadAll

    ' Close the file
    objFile.Close

    ' Reopen the file for writing
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, 2) ' 2 = ForWriting

    ' Write the new line at the beginning
    objFile.WriteLine header

    ' Write back the existing content
    objFile.Write existingContent

    ' Close the file
    objFile.Close
    
    'Rename the file
    If objFSO.GetFile(filePath).Name <> "STAMPS IMPORT.csv" Then
        objFSO.GetFile(filePath).Name = "STAMPS IMPORT.csv"
    End If

    WScript.Echo "Line added successfully."
Else
    WScript.Echo "File not found."
End If
Else
WScript.Echo "Usage: Stamps Import.vbs <file>"
End If
```

Comment: I tested your code and had no issue. What was your exact command line that generated an error?

Comment: I would recommend not using spaces in your script name or data file name. It just adds complication, but it does work as long as quotes are used. I'd also stay away from ever renaming files in a script. It's just something that has a higher chance of breaking compared to copying and deleting files.

Comment: @LesFerch
Script: C:\Users\*****\Documents\Stamps Import.vbs
Line:         38
Char: 3
Error: File already exists
Code: 800A003A
Source:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error

I modified the script to remove the space from the file name (and renamed the test file to the same) and it still fails.

Comment: @LesFerch For more context, I created a windows context menu item that runs the .vbs file using the filepath of the file right-clicked. Not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: OK, I see. If you pass "STAMPS IMPORT.csv" as an argument to your script, and the file already exists, it all works fine. However, if you pass any other filename to your script, and "STAMPS IMPORT.csv" exists, you get an error. As I mentioned, it is folly to rename files in a script, but now that you know the issue, you can rework your logic accordingly.

Comment: @LesFerch I guess I'm really confused about why, if the name of the file passed is STAMPS IMPORT.csv, that the script doesn't leave the if statement. Instead, it tries to rename the file still. I even had the script display the file name and it matches, but the if statement is still processed as if the file name doesn't match.

Comment: It's pretty simple. Your code translated to pseudo code says `if the file name passed on the command line is not equal to "STAMPS IMPORT.csv" then go ahead and rename it to  "STAMPS IMPORT.csv"`. It can't do that if the file exists. You're not actually checking if "STAMPS IMPORT.csv" already exists. And I did say that your issue occurs when the file name passed on the command line is NOT "STAMPS IMPORT.csv".